# toast message appears as if it's blinking - android

Tags: android, toast

How do I stop my application from displaying toast message many times?  Whenever I send sms whether it is to one, two or more contact, it always show the toast message multiple times. sometimes the toast appears as if its blinking while showing the "sms sent" message for about 2, 4, 18 times. i think it doubles the message "sms sent". if i send it to 1 number, it displays 2, and so on

```
try {

                    String message = "firealert";
                    String additionalMessage = send_input.getText().toString();
                    info.open();
                    ArrayList<String> data = info.getContactNumber();
                    info.close();
                    for(String contactNum : data)
                    {
                        sendSMS("0".concat(contactNum), message+" "+additionalMessage);
                        //sendSMS(contactNum, message+" "+additionalMessage);
                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS failed, please try again later!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

and used this code to display sms status

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
            {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
            {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a Toast variable.

```
private Toast t;

if(t!=null)    
   t.cancel();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

OR

```
if(t==null)    
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: maybe i'll try it again later in android phone. i'm using emulator right now.

Comment: i think it doubles the message "sms sent". if i send it to 1 number, it displays 2, and so on

Comment: i've tried your code, and it works for the first time i sent a message. then the second time i send a message it doubles the toast message. then again for the 3rd, 4th and so on...

Comment: i still don't know what happens here. i don't know if it has something to do with the way i get the phone number in my arraylist

Comment: but i guess it's not, it sends sms to cel numbers just once.

Answer (score 0):

Does the content of the sms have more than 160 chars ? Would it be possible that you see the Toast (content.length()/160) times ?
The sms might be splitted in several parts.

Comment: i think it doubles the message "sms sent". if i send it to 1 number, it displays 2, and so on